# HTTP 405 upon GET request when retrieving data

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I've been trying to make a REST API for a project. Never done this before technically, but one thing has thrown me for a bit of a baffle. I have a GET request to the server that properly returns a list of clients from my DbContext, but the second get action request I have in right now seems to only return an HTTP 405 error and I can't seem to find out as to why. Any ideas?

I've tried making it an actionResult, perhaps not properly? I know it functions when the action is just a string that returns "value" or another string, but doesn't seem to be able to return an object like the first GET method does

Working get method that gets all the clients in my repository

```cs
        // GET: api/Client
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Logic.Objects.Client> Get()
        {
            return _repository.GetClients();
        }
```

Second method that is returning a 405

```cs
        //GET: api/Client/5
        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
        public Task<Client> Get(Guid id)
        {
            return _repository.GetClientByIDAsync(id);
        }
```

Expected results would be if I added a client ID to api/Client/{id}, then it would return that specific client's information, rather than all of them, since that is a unique identifier and wont be the same as any other client, keeping with the RESTful mindset.

405 is the only error it throws unless its an incorrect ID that isnt a Guid, in which case it throw an exception within the method, which also lets me know that it IS getting there, something is just wrong with how it should be returning it's values?

EDIT: This is the whole controller class for those interested. Some methods just arent implemented yet, so they aren't really pertinent to the problem. At least I wouldnt think.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Dbnd.Logic.Interfaces;
using Dbnd.Logic.Objects;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Dbnd.Logic.Objects;

namespace Dbnd.Api.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ClientController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IRepository _repository;

        public ClientController(IRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }
        // GET: api/Client
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Logic.Objects.Client> Get()
        {
            return _repository.GetClients();
        }

        //GET: api/Client/5
        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
        public Task<Client> Get(Guid id)
        {
            return _repository.GetClientByIDAsync(id);
        }

        // POST: api/Client
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Post([FromBody, Bind("UserName, Email, PasswordHash")] Client client)
        {
            _repository.CreateClientAsync(client.UserName, client.Email, client.PasswordHash);

            return CreatedAtRoute("Get", client);
        }

        // PUT: api/Client/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE: api/ApiWithActions/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling this method then? Also, why are you converting an int to a Guid, why not just pass in a proper Guid in the first place?

Comment: Try this `return Ok(client);`

Comment: How can you parse an int to Guid?

Comment: Gave return `Ok(client);` a go, same results. Additionally made it a Guid in the first place rather than an int without parsing it. Still have a 405 from both outcomes. The method should, in theory be called when a user, for example types api/Client/(Whatever their ID is) in the url bar

Comment: Try changing the attribute over the second call to: [HttpGet("{id}")]

Comment: Given that a 405 is an invalid htpp method it would point to an issue with the HttpGet attribute

Comment: Changed the attribute to include what Ralph suggested with still no dice to fixing the 405, unfortunately

Comment: @Duk, could you post the entire controller class?

Comment: Ive edited to reflect my changes and included the controller class within the post now

Comment: New information is that this seems to actually work correctly on my colleague's computer, but not mine. Now my suspicion is something to do with some settings somewhere... 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have another api that works exactly the way you first posted (with actionResults). I couldn't find the problem in your code. It could be settings as you said, but it could also be the way you assemble your URL.

My best bet would be that your repository isn't returning the elemement but again, it should not give you a 405 but instead a 404 not found. I guess the response from your _repository is giving an error.

Maybe a troubleshooting idea is try a [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/) request to get and a breakpoint in your controller to see if you could see where the problem is.

I just created a test project to try and reproduce your problem, but it works fine. I followed this tutorial from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

And here is my resulting controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ClientsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ClientContext _context;

        public ClientsController(ClientContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Clients
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Client>>> GetClients()
        {
            return await _context.Clients.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Clients/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Client>> GetClient(long id)
        {
            var client = await _context.Clients.FindAsync(id);

            if (client == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return client;
        }

        // PUT: api/Clients/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutClient(long id, Client client)
        {
            if (id != client.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(client).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ClientExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/Clients
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Client>> PostClient(Client client)
        {
            _context.Clients.Add(client);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetClient", new { id = client.Id }, client);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Clients/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Client>> DeleteClient(long id)
        {
            var client = await _context.Clients.FindAsync(id);
            if (client == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Clients.Remove(client);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return client;
        }

        private bool ClientExists(long id)
        {
            return _context.Clients.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

I know it does not answer directly your question, but I hope it gives you food for thought and helps you with troubleshooting.